# How do I get separate list item after .map in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to Flutter and I have to make a list of rules where every item in the list is green and if you break a rule you can press it and change the color to red. I also have to have extensible.
I also have to have extensible. In my implementation from the YouTube tutorial, I saw that I used `.map()` to map the items in the list, but now when I have to press and change the color, all items change, not just one.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  bool isSelected = true;

  static const lawText =
      ' example text of the laws that are going to be implemented inside here. This is only to fill out the space at the moment';
  final List<Item> items = [
    Item(header: 'Law 1 ' , body: lawText),
    Item(header: 'Law 2 ' , body: lawText),
    Item(header: 'Law 3 ' , body: lawText),
    Item(header: 'Law 4 ' , body: lawText),
    Item(header: 'Law 5 ' , body: lawText),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    drawer: NavBar(),
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('§ Regel'),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
      //crossAxisAlignment : crossAxisAlignment,
      child:ExpansionPanelList(
        expansionCallback: (index, isExpanded) {
          setState(() => items[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded);
        },
        children: items
            .map((item) => ExpansionPanel(
          isExpanded: item.isExpanded,
          headerBuilder:(context, isExpanded) => ListTile(
            tileColor: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
            onTap:  () => setState(() => isSelected = !isSelected),
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            title:Text(
              item.header,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
          ),
          body: ListTile(
            title: Text(item.body, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20) ),
            //tileColor: Colors.lightGreen,
            //onTap:  () => setState(() => isSelected = !isSelected),
          ),
        ))
            .toList(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class Item {
  final String header;
  final String body;
  bool isExpanded;

  Item({
    required this.header,
    required this.body,
    this.isExpanded = false,
  });
}
```

[image][image]

I try to do everything with `ListTile` instead of normal list.
I also tried using `elementAt(index)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

change this

```
tileColor: isSelected ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
```

to this:

```
tileColor: item.isExpanded ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
```

you have to use bool condition from parent panel

[image]

Comment: Hello pmatatias , thank you for your answer. This changes color but when i press on expanded. I need expanded to stay as it is and change color when i press on Law 1 lets say. Or i could make it that "expand" button is "change color" button but then i have to handle somehow to expand item from list when i press on it.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which tile you click, the `isSelected` will be changed, and every tile will recognize the change since the `isSelected` condition determines which color you would like to display.

So, You have to change the type of your `isSelected` from `bool` to `String`
, which when you tap it, you can set the `isSelected` to the label, in this way, flutter will know which tile you want to change.

```
String selected = '';
```

in your tile property

```
tileColor: selected == items[index].header ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
onTap:  () => setState(() => selected = items[index].header),
```

However, for the best practice, either you can set a new field `id` for the Item class, or you can use `asMap()` to declare the indexes. Because sometimes, the headers could be same.

Comment: Hello Noah , thank you for your answer. Im not sure that i understand completely . 
If i do as you said and change bool isSelected to String selected and implement snippet that you wrote what happens is that again whole list changes the color but only once and then it doesnt react anymore.